# que puedo hacer para construir la app en Android studio problemas "offline mode"

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

este es el codigo del gradle

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.8.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

El error:

```
>  A problem occurred configuring root project 'restaurant'.
> > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
>    > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.8.1.
>      Required by:
>          project :
>       > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.8.1 available for offline mode.
```

y tengo todas las dependencias instaladas!!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por favor ayudemne! actualice el android a 4.1 y el gradle y ahora me da error los mismos proyectos que antes funcionaban!!